# SSH Works fine but i cant connect to SFTP

Tags: centos, ftp, sftp

I am facing strange issue, I am using Centos6. I can connect to ssh but i am unable to connect to SFTP. now the strange part is, if i restart server, SFTP starts working again for few mins, and then again goes time out.

It shows only 1 error, server time out. I tried to even create new user, but not worked.

When it was new server, it was all working fine, this have been happening from last week.
I even checked the sshd_config file, the passwordauthentication is enabled, the ssh path on last line is enabled as well.

Comment: Anything in the logs at the time of failure-after-reboot?

Comment: I am using filezilla & coda, in filezilla it says                Error: Connection timed out
Error: Could not connect to server

Comment: Not client-side; server-side.

Comment: Its not showing any errors :(

Comment: I am not a pro user, sir but is there any thing like clearing cache?anywhere in ssh? which might be a problem? But SSH is working just fine. server load is  0.25.

Answer (score 1):

In you client side, try `ssh-add` command before (one time only) start the sftp session

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, but how do i add it in Filezilla & coda?

Comment: if you run ``$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`` (change key path) in your client, Filezilla probably work.

Comment: Important: Filezilla logon type must be "interactive"